# How to write white spaces in a CStdioFile?

Tags: c++, mfc

I'm using a `CStdioFile` and trying to leave a number of white spaces before writing a CString.
I tried `CStdioFile.Seek(iNumOfSpaces, CStdioFile::current)` the i write the string.
the problem is that when I open the file in Notepad++ it writes NUL instead of the white spaces.
How to write the white spaces to be viewed as white not NUL?
Thanks in advance

Comment: Have you tried padding the CString with spaces before writing it?

Comment: the number of white spaces is variable not fixed. Is there any way to use padding without looping ? @rrirower

Comment: Since you know the number of spaces ahead of time, that should not stop you from composing a padded string.

Comment: Is there any way to use padding without looping like a regular expression for example ? @rrirower

Comment: Take a look at CStringT::Format.  You should be able to use the format specifiers to craft a padded string.

Comment: `Seek` moves the file pointer, it does not add any content and in a new file, seeking forward past where you have written is not good. Why not just output a string of spaces before you output the string?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

1.

```
CString hh="i7mjmhb";
CString h(' ',31);
hh=h+hh;
```

2.

```
CString hh=L"i7mjmhb";
CString h(L' ',31);
hh=h+hh;
```

With files it's bad  not to know forward is it ascii or unicode stuff

Answer (score 5):

You misunderstood what `CFile::Seek()` method does. It moves the file pointer to a specified position, absolutely or relatively. It does not add/modify the content of the file.

Instead you should use `CString::Format()` method that supports padding. Here is an example that shows how to use it:

```
CString s;  
s.Format(_T("|%-10s|"), _T("Data")); // left-align
s.Format(_T("|%10s|"), _T("Data")); // right-align
```

The result string is going to look like:

```
|Data      |
|      Data|
```

Here is an example that shows how to implement dynamic (variable length) padding:

```
CString s;  
int n = 10;
s.Format(_T("|%-*s|"), n, _T("Data")); // left-align
s.Format(_T("|%*s|"), n, _T("Data")); // right-align
```

Comment: Thanks for your interest. 
but I need the spaces from the left side and the number of spaces will be in an integer variable. I tried to loop and append the spaces but it takes a long time cause the file is big @Andrew

Comment: You can create format-control string/specifier dynamically based on your int variable.

Comment: I've provided an example for variable-length padding. Enjoy.

Comment: I wrote the following function to test but it doesn't work 
could you please told me what is the error?
And also i don't want to write the character **|** .
Thank you very much
`void Test ()
{
  CString strPath = _T("d:\\test\\asd.pba");
  CStdioFile File;
  if(File.Open(strPath, CFile::modeCreate | CFile::modeWrite | CFile::typeText))
  {
    CString strLine;
    strLine.Format(_T("|%*s|"), 9, _T("CStdioFile Test padding\n")); 
    File.WriteString(strLine);
    File.Close();
  }
}` @Andrew

Comment: Remove | characters from format specifier if you don't need it. Could you please be more specific what does not work?

Comment: As far as I can see you string *CStdioFile Test padding* is longer than 9 characters. So it will not be padded.

Comment: Use `CString::Left()` method if you need to truncate strings in case if you are required to use fixed length strings.

Comment: I don't want to use fixed length strings.
this function is only for test.
all I need is that how to append a number of white spaces in the beginning of a `CString`.
and the method 
`CString strLine=_T("CStdioFile test padding");`
`CString strSpaces(L' ',iNumOfSpaces);`
`strLine=strSpaces + strLine;`
is working with me
Thank you very much @Andrew

Comment: last will fail in ascii environment.

Comment: @АлексейНеудачин: It will compile (and work) just fine, even when using MBCS encoding. The [CString](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5bzxfsea.aspx#cstringt__cstringt) implementation provides conversion c'tors, that construct a narrow string representation from a wide string (unless you explicitly defined the `_CSTRING_DISABLE_NARROW_WIDE_CONVERSION` preprocessor symbol).

Comment: so if you mean absent unicode then your post is just lie

Comment: @АлексейНеудачин: The `CStringA` class template instantiation has a conversion c'tor, taking a `wchar_t` argument. `CStringA str(L' ', 42);` compiles just fine, and has the desired effect. If you believe this to be a lie, fire up Visual Studio, and pay close attention to its opinion on the matter.

Comment: compiler wouldn't recognize L'' stuff. If you wanna see unicode-free system install windows millenium + msvc on vm.What you'd type is unicode ver

Comment: or install vs2005

Comment: @АлексейНеудачин: Again, you are wrong. What's worse, you are beating a dead horse. The few developers maintaining MFC code targeting Windows 95 very well understand MBCS encoding, as well as the limited Unicode support in Visual Studio 6. Contrary to your claim, VS6 is very much capable of parsing wide string literals (`L"..."`). In addition, the VS6 implementation of [CString](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa314317(v=vs.60).aspx) also had the conversion c'tors. The code in my previous comment compiles in VS6.

Comment: yea lie i mean as wrong.I remember well vs6 times.there are two versions of mfc there.mfc42 and mfc42u. And mfc42's stuff cant hold something wide.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/130711/discussion-between---and-iinspectable).

Comment: No one claimed, that `CStringA` were storing a wide character string. The point in question was simply, that a `CStringA` can be **constructed** from a wide character string, by way of a conversion c'tor. Anyway, stop beating a dead horse. Developers that need to support Windows 95 are likely more familiar with the intricacies, than you are, judging by your contributions to this answer.